# Looping through an object without using Object.entries() on each key of the inner object

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to loop through a nested object without specifying keys. I mean just to take the name of the object to do the loop. Is there any method to achieve it?
You can see at the bottom what I tried. It actually works, but I want to know if there is a way to do this without mentioning the keys(hero, monster)

Object to loop through:

```js
const characterData = {
  hero: {
    name: "Wizard",
    avatar: "images/wizard.png",
    health: 60,
    diceCount: 3,
    currentDiceScore: []
  },
  monster: {
    name: "Orc",
    avatar: "images/orc.png",
    health: 10,
    diceCount: 1,
    currentDiceScore: []
  },
};

Object.entries(characterData.hero).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first iterate over [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) which, in this case, are the nested objects `hero`, `monster` and so on.. using [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), and then your code that iterates over [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) again using [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

- But notice that in the `callbackFn` function is used the **square brackets** [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and inside the `console.log()` [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
const characterData = {hero: {name: "Wizard",avatar: "images/wizard.png",health: 60,diceCount: 3,currentDiceScore: []},monster: {name: "Orc",avatar: "images/orc.png",health: 10,diceCount: 1,currentDiceScore: []},}

Object.values(characterData)
  .forEach(o => 
    Object.entries(o)
      .forEach(([k, v]) => 
        console.log(`${k}: ${v}`)))
```

Comment: Thanks Yosvel.
I understand what you did. However, I could not do a good  grasp of the square brackets in the second forEach. I know it might has something to do with arrays but I cant put the idea of what is actually doing down.

Comment: @ArgentumCoder  Object.entries  callback sends two parameters as an array tuple  `[key, value]`, eg..  `[[key,value], [key,value],...]`  so -> `([k, v]) => ` destructors these into k & v.